# Create a Static Method that takes a Deedle dataframe as a parameters and returns a Deedle dataframe in C#

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

I'm trying to create a static method that takes Deedle dataframes as parameters and returns a Deedle dataframes in C#. What is the the type to use when declaring such a static method and what is the format to declare a very generic form of a Deedle Dataframe? Below I created a static method that takes doubles as input parameters, instantiates a blank variable of type double in the method, and returns a double. Essentially, I'd like to do something very similar with Deedle dataframes.

```
namespace MathTestJunk
{
    class ScrapClass
    {
        public static double SimpleMethod(double Input1, double Input2)
        {
            double TempDouble;
            TempDouble = (Input1 * 5.0) + (Input2 * + 9.2);
            return TempDouble;
        }

    }
}
```

Loading up the dataframes from CSV's looks like this:

```
Dataframe1 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/Users/Table1.csv");
Dataframe2 = Frame.ReadCsv("C:/Users/Table2.csv");
```

Comment: Never worked with deedle, but as far as I can see, it's a API for accessing tableform data, (like csv/datarows). What do you want it to accept as parameter and return?

Comment: Currently, Deedle doesn't have an elegant method for performing an in memory LEFT JOIN on two data tables where one of the columns to be joined ON is not unique for every row. I'd like to write a static method to accomplish this. Such a method would to accept two dataframes as parameters and return another dataframe. @Jeroen van Langen

Comment: Can you write an example about how you create/load the data for these dataframes? So i can see how you declare them

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen   You can load the dataframes from CSV files:    dataframe1 =Frame.ReadCsv("C:/Users/MyFile.CSV");

Comment: What type is it? `Frame` ?

Comment: Yes. Frame @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: I need more info, like the type name returned by `Frame.ReadCsv()`. I think, you can simply pass a Frame to your static method and create a new Frame inside and return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Deedle.Frame<int, string> SomeStaticMethod(Deedle.Frame<int, string> InputDf1, Deedle.Frame<int, string> InputDf2)
{
        var OutputDf = InputDf1.Join(InputDf2);

        return OutputDf;    
}
```